# SQL oracle : How to get date Between today and last year

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, where-clause

I would like to know how to get the date column that's between today and today(lastyear)
Please help mee...

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_X
WHERE X_DATE BETWEEN (SYSDATE) AND (SYSDATE-365);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starter, you have the range bounds the wrong way around (the lower bound is greater than the upper bound), so your query cannot return any row.

Then: not all years have 365 days - use `add_months()` instead:

```
where x_date between add_months(trunc(current_date), -12) and current_date
```

I am unsure whether you want to take the time component into account or not. Assuming that you want the records until today included, you would use:

```
where x_date >= add_months(trunc(current_date), -12) 
  and x_date <  trunc(current_date) + 1
```

If you don't want today, then use `trunc(current_date)` instead of `trunc(current_date) + 1`.

Comment: Whoa this is what i waiting for ! I try all the way but i didn't understand to it,but you help me from that thanks!

Comment: Do you have this in a JPA form ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, both `sysdate` and `current_date` in Oracle have time components.  If you want the time component, then fine.  In general, though, you probably want:

```
where x_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12) and
      x_date < trunc(sysdate)
```

Note:  It is unclear whether you want to include the current date or not, so you might want:

```
where x_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -12) + interval '1' day and
      x_date < trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' day
```

Comment: Thanks ! i didn't know that sysdate contain time i didn't know that before, You help me a lot thanks !